# Strange navigation pane

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

[image]

My appendices.tex file begins with

```
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{AppendicesTOC}
```

and the appendix was included in the main text using the command

```
\include{appendices}
```

I want the AppendicesTOC appear as a separate 'chapter' (same hierarchy as 'My 2nd paper') but it appears as a subsection under the section 'conclusion.'

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the value of tocdepth just for the appendices. It's probably not necessary to reset it afterwards, since the appendices are at the end.

In the appendices tex file, ensure the counter of the the variable `{tocdepth}` is set to zero.

```
\begin{appendices}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
\end{appendices}
```